# Intermittent crash when updating UI from onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is the stacktrace:

```
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at ca.TwentyTwenty.cropinspection.GeneralSpinnerDialogFragment$AsyncSaver.onPostExecute(GeneralSpinnerDialogFragment.java:140)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at ca.TwentyTwenty.cropinspection.GeneralSpinnerDialogFragment$AsyncSaver.onPostExecute(GeneralSpinnerDialogFragment.java:1)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-10 09:14:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code

```
FieldDetailItem fd = ((FieldActivity) getActivity()).fieldDetails.get(list_position);
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with fieldDetails possibly not being around when the Asynctask comes back, but I am not sure what else to do here. What are my options?

Thanks.

Comment: Split your faulty line in multiple statements and check which one returns null. It could possibly come from `getActivity()` (if this code is executed before the `Fragment`'s `onActivityCreated()`) or the `fieldDetails` being at `null`.

Comment: It looks like the problem is coming from a null fieldDetails. fieldDetails is a data member of the parent activity for the fragments I am calling. Why would that be null? The crash comes up randomly on similar calls at different times.

Comment: It's hard to tell why without having the source of your activity and your fragment. You have to double check that `fieldDetails` is properly initialized before your create your fragment, or not set to `null` at some point. You'd probably want to use breakpoints at your fragment's creation and at any modification of the `fieldDetails` variable.

Comment: I think the key to my question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897949/calling-activity-method-from-fragment-nullpointerexception I am going to try to intialize a fieldActivity data memember onAttach to ensure that it is always around before I use it.